# Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest'. (MT5212)

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin, asihttprequest, xamarin-studio

I have just done an update of `Xamarin Studio` and my `iOS` application now gives several linking errors when I try to compile it. All the linking errors pertain to my libOfflineRequest static library that makes use of [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Here is an example of one of the linking errors from the build output:

```
error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIHTTPRequest'.
error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/brucehill/Projects/Mobileforms/StaticLibs/OfflineRequest/libOfflineRequest.a(ASIHTTPRequest.o) (Location related to previous error)
error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/brucehill/Projects/Mobileforms/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/registrar.armv7.o (Location related to previous error)
```

It seems to me that my library is clashing with `mtouch-cache`, but I am not using `mtouch-cache`, so is there some way from me to exclude this during linking?

Comment: Do you define an ASIHTTPRequest class in your own code?

Comment: Yes, the library libOfflineRequest.a that I am linking in makes use of ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Could you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com, attaching the project so that we can have a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else encounters this issue, here is how I resolved it. I right clicked on my project, navigated to `iOS Build` and then in the field 'Additional mtouch arguments' I added the following option:

--registrar:oldstatic

Once I had added that my application compiled correctly again.

Comment: I tried this, and got "error : The legacy registrars (--registrar:legacy|legacystatic|legacydynamic) are not supported with the Unified API"

Comment: Hmmm. It could be that this option has been removed in a more recent update of Xamarin Studio. :( I have not done any updates since I did this post.